# Where can I get ensembl Medaka genome for RNAseq

Tags: rna-seq, ensembl

I am trying to map a RNA-seq dataset using ensembl genome for medaka fish.

From here http://uswest.ensembl.org/Oryzias_latipes/Info/Index

when I click on a `Download DNA sequence (FASTA)` I am forwarded here ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-98/fasta/oryzias_latipes/dna/

where I have a huge number of `.fa.gz` files and I am just looking for a single file, that I can use.

While when I am downloading medaka genome from NCBI (and using this technique) http://www.metagenomics.wiki/tools/fastq/ncbi-ftp-genome-download I have my ncbi genome in one file.

How can I get an ensembl genome in one file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the ones without a chromosome number in the filename. Those files are the whole genome.

Comment: deleted my answer, this is much better

Comment: Thank you Emily, but is that link located on a same page?? I mean the one " without a chromosome number in"? And you said oneS - there are multiple medaka genomes?

Comment: Yes, they're all listed in the same folder. Check the README to see what you want in terms of toplevel, repeat masking etc, but they're all there.

Comment: Thank you, but still... what I see is for example 
```Oryzias_latipes.ASM223467v1.dna.primary_assembly.1.fa.gz
Oryzias_latipes.ASM223467v1.dna_rm.primary_assembly.1.fa.gz Oryzias_latipes.ASM223467v1.dna_sm.primary_assembly.1.fa.gz``` but I cannot find something like ```Oryzias_latipes.ASM223467v1.fa.gz``` Sorry I am really new to bioinformatics and lots of things are new to me while they are somewhat obvious for the experts.. Thank you!

Comment: rm and sm refer to the repeat masking. rm is full repeat masking, all the repeats are replaced by Ns. sm is soft-masking, the repeats are in lower case. The other file has no repeat masking.